# Does implementing the Sync trait change the compiler output?

Tags: rust

If I mark my struct as `Sync` will the compiler output differ? Will the compiler implement some `Mutex`-like magic?

```
struct MyStruct {
    data: RefCell<u32>,
}
unsafe impl Sync for MyStruct {}
unsafe impl Send for MyStruct {}
```

Comment: I guess you could try that yourself and see if the assembly differs?

Comment: "Will the compiler implement some Mutex-like magic?" No. `Send` and `Sync` are "marker traits". By implementing these types, you promise the compiler that your types fulfil the contract for those traits. You have to `unsafe impl` these traits because the compiler can't check you're doing it correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My understanding of Sync and Send traits got a lot better.

Comment: Note that in cases where the compiler can check that you're doing it correctly, then you don't need to because "[_This trait is automatically implemented when the compiler determines it's appropriate._](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Send.html)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler uses a mechanism named "language items" to reference items (types, traits, etc.) that are defined in a library (usually `core`) but are used by the compiler, whether that be in code generated by the compiler, for validating the code or for producing specialized error messages.

`Send` and `Sync` are defined in the `core` library. `Sync` is a language item, but `Send` isn't. The only reference to `Sync` I could find in the compiler is where it checks that the type of a `static` variable implements `Sync`. (`Send` and `Sync` used to be more special to the compiler. Before auto traits were added to the language, they were implemented as "auto traits" explicitly.)

Other than that, the compiler doesn't care about what `Send` and `Sync` mean. It's the libraries (specifically, types/functions that are generic over `Send`/`Sync` types) that give the traits their meaning.

Neither trait influences what code is emitted by the compiler regarding a particular type. Making a type "thread-safe" is not something that can be done automatically. Consider a struct with many fields: even if the fields are all atomic types, a partially updated struct might not be in a valid state. The compiler doesn't know about the invariants of a particular type; only the programmer knows them. Therefore, it's the programmer's responsibility to make the type thread-safe.

Comment: *"`Sync` is a language item, but `Send` isn't"* I don't understand this. Can you further explain this please? *The Rust Programming Language*-book says: *"two concurrency concepts are embedded in the language: `Sync` and `Send`"* As far as I understand "the language" and the `core`-Birary are the same thing? https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-04-extensible-concurrency-sync-and-send.html

Comment: The `core` library is distributed with Rust and is an underlying building block of the `std` library. Almost every Rust program or library will use `core` (either directly or through `std`), so it might as well be considered part of the language; Rust wouldn't be the same without `Send` and `Sync`. Perhaps the person who wrote this part of the book didn't realize that `Send` and `Sync` aren't so deeply integrated into the compiler anymore, or it was written back when they were.